# Spring Boot Configure DevTools in Modular Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-platform-module-system

I'm new to Java modules. I've been trying to make DevTools work with jigsaw modules but I get the following error

> Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.IllegalAccessException:
>   class org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher (in
>   module spring.boot.devtools) cannot access class
>   com.thanosfisherman.mancala.MancalaApplication (in module
>   com.thanosfisherman.mancala) because module
>   com.thanosfisherman.mancala does not export
>   com.thanosfisherman.mancala to module spring.boot.devtools

What should I put into my `module-info.java` file in so that the app can run normally?

`module-info.java`

```
 module com.thanosfisherman.mancala {
    requires spring.web;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.boot;
}
```

Note that I'm using Gradle. Here is my gradle config script

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.thanosfisherman'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtimeOnly('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtimeOnly('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

**EDIT:** I read somewhere that spring uses reflection to read the module file so I have to add the `open` keyword like so.

```
open module com.thanosfisherman.mancala {
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.web;
}
```

Now My app runs normally **without** the devtools dependency but again throws a different error **with** the dependency.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration
>   due to javax/sql/DataSource not found. Make sure your own
>   configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you
>   are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a
>   @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but on jdk8 (no modules involved) because my main class wasn't public.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
/*public*/ class MyApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(LocationsTest.class, args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That means code on the classpath cannot access this module by default. It needs to be manually added with the `--add-modules` option of Java 9’s `javac`.

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += ["--add-modules", "spring.boot.devtools"]
}
```

so add them step by step.

Comment: I added that into my gradle script but the same error still occurs.

Comment: Have you added `spring.boot.devtools` to module file?

Comment: Yes I tried to add `requires spring.boot.devtools;` but Intellij Marks it as error saying `Module is not in dependencies: spring.boot.devtools`

Comment: if you look at the gradle script the dependency for devtools is set to `runtimeOnly` by default from `https://start.spring.io/` So either maybe I have to completely exclude it from java module system? I don't know.

Comment: try to run it without devtools

Comment: Have a look at my revised question.

Comment: Yeah, I see. But look at here - https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/890. It looks like Gradle doesn't officially support Jigsaw. There are some plugins to do that.

Comment: Ah great I wasn't aware of that -.-